# Как на Perl выполнять несколько команд одновременно

Tags: perl

Поясняю:

```
print "Введите команду:\n";
chomp ($kom = >STDIN>);
if ($kom = <условие>)
{
   оператор 1;
   оператор 2;
}
else
{
   оператор 3;
}
```

И чтобы при выполнении любой ветки ветвления, скрипт продолжал ожидания ввода команды и не дожидаясь завершения первой начинал выполнять условие второй? Спасибо.

Comment: называется это fork или select мб подойдет... (правда с stdin я не уверен)

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Можно запускать новый процесс для выполнения каждой введённой команды:

```perl
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp();

    next if $_ eq '';
    last if $_ eq 'exit';

    fork() and next;

    # тут обрабатываем введённую команду

    exit();
}
```

Если по окончании цикла ввода надо дождаться окончания обработки всех введённых команд, можно сделать так:

```perl
use POSIX ':sys_wait_h';

my %children;

while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp();

    next if $_ eq '';
    last if $_ eq 'exit';

    my $pid = fork();

    if ($pid) {
        $children{$pid} = 1;
        next;
    }

    # тут обрабатываем введённую команду

    exit();
}

# ждём окончания всех процессов обработки
while (keys(%children)) {
    for (keys(%children)) {
        my $ret = waitpid($_, WNOHANG);

        next unless $ret;
        delete($children{$_}) if $ret != -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитай здесь: [Мини экскурс в AnyEvent - пишем паука](http://likhatskiy.livejournal.com/1966.html)

```
use AnyEvent;

$| = 1; print "enter your name> ";

my $name_ready = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $wait_for_input = AnyEvent->io (
    fh => \*STDIN, poll => "r",
    cb => sub { $name_ready->send (scalar <STDIN>) }
);

# делаем что нидь еще

# теперь ждем и подставляем данные на входе
my $name = $name_ready->recv;

undef $wait_for_input; # watcher нам больше не нужен

print "your name is $name\n";
```

use AnyEvent;
как-то так

- https://gist.github.com/mishin/6449631
- [Всё, что вы хотели знать об AnyEvent, но боялись спросить](http://pragmaticperl.com/issues/01/pragmaticperl-01-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1-anyevent-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C.html#.UjcWQ1NlxXA)

Comment: как событийная модель относится к вопросу ?  вот к этой его части

> **и не дожидаясь завершения** первой начинал выполнять условие второй?

*круто что вы знаете про AnyEvent но оно здесь не к месту.*